# multiple layouts/layout transitions in a python plasmoid

Tags: python, kde-plasma, plasmoid

I'm doing a **little python plasmoid** that deals with remote resources.
Here's the code : [glpoid](http://ee_lars@bitbucket.org/ee_lars/glpioid)

It offers a **view of tickets** (the default one), a view that let the user **filling and sending a new ticket**, and a last one to **see a ticket detail**...

My problem is that i don't know how to "close" the current layout when i'm passing to another view (or make it disappear).

For each layout, i define items that i add to the layout definition and last i display the new layout :

Initially, i display the default view with **self.view_tickets_ui()**.
Each layout is definied in **name_ui()** methods which each redefine the layout and pass it to the applet.

To resume it's defined like this:

```
class GLPIApplet(plasmascript.Applet):
    def __init__(self,parent,args=None):
        plasmascript.Applet.__init__(self,parent)

    def init(self):
        self.setHasConfigurationInterface(False)
        self.setAspectRatioMode(Plasma.Square)
        self.resize(400,650)
        # new ticket button
        self.new = Plasma.PushButton()
        self.new.setText('Nouveau Ticket')
        self.connect(self.new, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.new_ticket_ui)
        # refresh button
        self.refresh = Plasma.PushButton()
        self.refresh.setText('Rafraichir')
        self.connect(self.refresh, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.view_tickets_ui)       
        # initialize
        self.view_tickets_ui()

    def view_tickets_ui(self, message=None):
        # layout of ticket view
        self.layout = QGraphicsLinearLayout(Qt.Vertical)
        self.layout.itemSpacing(3)           
        self.layout.addItem(self.new)
        self.view_tickets()
        self.layout.addItem(self.refresh)
        self.applet.setLayout(self.layout)

    def new_ticket_ui(self, message=None):
        # layout of a new ticket
        self.layout = QGraphicsLinearLayout(Qt.Vertical)
        self.layout.itemSpacing(3)
        message_label = Plasma.Label()
        message_label.setText('the message:')            
        self.layout.addItem(message_label)
        self.applet.setLayout(self.layout)
```

Here **init** just defines some buttons, and then call **view_tickets_ui()** that put some items and display the layout.
If i call **new_ticket_ui()** after, it will add elements to the current layout... so both are displayed on the same place.

How can i manage that please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Plasma.TabBar` with hidden tabs and switch between them, as mentioned on IRC. Connect the `clicked` signals to slots that switch among tabs and everything should be fine.

Also, a note on style: you should use the [new signal/slot API](http://riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/pyqt4ref.html#new-style-signal-and-slot-support) whenever possible:

```
self.connect(self.refresh, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.view_tickets_ui)
```

should become

```
self.refresh.clicked.connect(self.view_tickets_ui).
```

Comment: Thanks for these advices Einar, i'm modifying my code to see the result and then say you how it is going.